# Speed up the launch of a simple android activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have an activity which gets a string and integer from intent when launched and accordingly sets a background from resource image (About 200kb) and the text on `AutoResizeTextView` according to it. The `AutoResizeTextView` also uses a **typeface**. Asides from that there are 3 buttons which just launch other activity with intent extras.

Here's the code-

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class test extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int wall;
    public String set1;
    public TextView tv;
    public Button b1,b2,b3;
    public Typeface font4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        font4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/lesserconcernregular.ttf");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quoto);
        Bundle appdat=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(appdat!=null){
            try {
                set1 = appdat.getString("exact1");
                wall = appdat.getInt("exact2");
            }
            catch (Exception a){
                set1 ="Error";
                wall =1;
            }
        }
        else{
            set1="No data";
            wall=1;
        }
        final RelativeLayout rlay=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlay);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textoo);
        tv.setText(set1);
        tv.setTypeface(font4);


        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViews);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        switch (wall){
            case 1:
                rlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.id1);
                break;
            case 2:
                rlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.id2);
                break;
           //So on till 50         
        }
       rlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               moveTaskToBack(true);
           }
       });
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,137,244,95));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(33,0,0,0));
                Intent k=new Intent(test.this,Main2Activity.class);
                k.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(k);
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,137,244,95));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(33,0,0,0));
                Intent qu=new Intent(test.this,wallandshare.class);
                qu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                qu.putExtra("exact1",set1);
                qu.putExtra("exact2",wall);
                qu.putExtra("exact3", 1);
                startActivity(qu);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rlay.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,137,244,95));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(33,0,0,0));
                Intent qu=new Intent(test.this,wallandshare.class);
                qu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                qu.putExtra("exact1",set1);
                qu.putExtra("exact2",wall);
                qu.putExtra("exact3", 2);
                startActivity(qu);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`AutoResizeTextView` has been defined in XML of layout and I have used a simple `TextView` to change it.

The problem is that when this activity is launched the screen goes white and takes a long time to load. Is there anything I can do to make it load up real fast?

Comment: Test is on another device

Comment: remove mAdView.loadAd from onCreate and add it in onStart or in onResume

Comment: @Amy It's varying on some devices it was a bit faster due to their hardware configuration but the goal is to create an app for all devices but I fixed by problem now by using Handler and also shifting AdView to OnStart. Thanks

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar Thanks man I did shift AdView to OnStart and also using Handler fastened my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are loading so much data as soon as the Activity is Launched.
Use Handler and run the code after some milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you so much, I let the Handler changer the background after few milliseconds and it worked!

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely what I needed!